# Set selected display value of select option box

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a selection in my drop down where the display text is different than the actual value.  Once I make my selection I want the actual HTML that is displayed in the SELECT box to show the actual value, not the selected text.

I have this so far.  It almost works, but once I make the selection, it DOES set the viewable field to the value, but if I click the dropdown a second time the initial selectable choices are no longer there, just the values.

```
<select size="1" style="width: 28mm; border: 1px solid;"" name="Priority"
        id="Priority" onChange="setDevices(this);">
    <option selected><? print($row[Priority]); ?></option>
    <option value="Pri1">This is Priority 1</option>
    <option value="Pri2">This is Priority 2</option>
    <option value="Pri3">This is Priority 3</option>
    <option value="Pri4">This is Priority 4</option>
</select>

function setDevices(elem) {
    elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].innerHTML = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bringing this forward to 2019, we can now use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store the previous info

```js
function setDevices(elem) {
  let arrMeta = elem.dataset.meta.split("|");
  let index = parseInt(arrMeta[0], 10);
  let text = arrMeta[1];

  //Reset the old text
  elem.options[index].innerHTML = text;

  //Set the meta from the new
  elem.dataset.meta = elem.selectedIndex + "|" + elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

  //Update the new
  elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].innerHTML = elem.value;

}
```

```html
<select size="1" style="width: 28mm; border: 1px solid;" name="Priority" id="Priority" onchange="setDevices(this);" data-meta="0|">
  <option selected>
    <? print($row[Priority]); ?>
  </option>
  <option value="Pri1">This is Priority 1</option>
  <option value="Pri2">This is Priority 2</option>
  <option value="Pri3">This is Priority 3</option>
  <option value="Pri4">This is Priority 4</option>
</select>
```

You could of course use 2 data attributes, one for the previous selected index and one for the previous text.

Answer (score 0):

***edited 02/02/14***

So you want "This is Priority 1" to change to "Pri1" when selected, and change back when unselected?

You'll need to store the original value somewhere when changing it the first time, and add some code to restore that stored value when the selection changes.

You could use the "rel" attribute maybe:

```
<select size="1" style="width: 28mm; border: 1px solid;"" name="Priority" id="Priority" onchange="setDevices(this);">
  <option selected><? print($row[Priority]); ?></option>
  <option value="Pri1" rel="This is Priority 1">This is Priority 1</option>
  <option value="Pri2" rel="This is Priority 2">This is Priority 2</option>
  <option value="Pri3" rel="This is Priority 3">This is Priority 3</option>
  <option value="Pri4" rel="This is Priority 4">This is Priority 4</option>
</select>

<script>
  function setDevices(elem){
    for(i=0; i<elem.options.length; i++) {
      elem.options[i].innerHTML = (i == elem.selectedIndex) ? elem.options[i].value : elem.options[i].getAttribute("rel");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Almost; and Thank you!!  I think we are on the right track.  It still returns "Pri2" as desired but when I click the dropdown again to change my choice all other choices now show "undefined" and my selected choice still says "Pri2" instead of the original "This is Priority 2".  Maybe I can sacrifice a hidden text field for this and return that value back in....

Comment: Just to add some clarification to my request... I am looking to have an HTML SELECT dropdown that when the arrow is clicked to dropdown the box, I see a list of choices that contain the full text as described above.  Then when I make a choice, it does not return the full option text of "This is Priority 2", instead it returns just the value.  If I decide to click the drop down list again, I still see all my text choices as I did before I made any selection.  I must add that I did miss the rel="Original text" in your example above.  Once I added this to my code. But same result as original ques

Comment: I updated the Javascript in my answer so it should now work in all browsers (previously worked in Chrome but not Firefox, it seems).

Comment: BUT - this still won't do quite what you're after. Sounds to me like you want the dropdown list to contain the fulltext options but the box itself to contain the value. My answer gets you close, but the selected option will appear as value-only in both the list and the box. Perhaps you should look at using a fake dropdown instead of a real <select> element if you want this much control - I think eBay have something like this in their "my purchases" page.